# Animate elements one at a time

Tags: jquery, animate.css

I would like to make four `div`'s with the class of `.stat`div animate one at a time using jQuery.

I was thinking I had to use the `$.each()` method to loop through the divs in order to animate them one at a time, however they all animate at the same time, instead of 1 by 1.

Any thoughts of why would be greatly appreciated.

[Here is the jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8t881403/1/)

**HTML**

```
  <section class="sub-nav">
    <nav>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#mission">mission</a></li>
      <li><a href="#why-cs">why-cs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#learning-experience">learning experience</a></li>
      <li><a href="#success">success</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </nav>
  </section>
<div id="mission"> mission</div>
<div id="why-cs">
  why-cs
          <div class="stat col-md-3 hide">
          <img class="center-block" src="https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0e/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg/64px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg.png&imgrefurl=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piste&h=64&w=64&tbnid=b1-OSFz6e0HHrM:&docid=PkB0TDgkdOkHwM&ei=62ZlVqyJAYGz-wGjuK4I&tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwjsqp6tzMnJAhWB2T4KHSOcCwEQMwhGKCIwIg" alt="statistic">
          <p class="center-block num"> 100 </p>
          <div class="center-block statistic"> statistic #1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat col-md-3 hide">
          <img class="center-block" src="https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0e/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg/64px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg.png&imgrefurl=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piste&h=64&w=64&tbnid=b1-OSFz6e0HHrM:&docid=PkB0TDgkdOkHwM&ei=62ZlVqyJAYGz-wGjuK4I&tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwjsqp6tzMnJAhWB2T4KHSOcCwEQMwhGKCIwIg" alt="statistic">
          <p class="center-block num"> 100 </p>
          <div class="center-block statistic"> statistic #2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat col-md-3 hide">
          <img class="center-block" src="https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0e/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg/64px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg.png&imgrefurl=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piste&h=64&w=64&tbnid=b1-OSFz6e0HHrM:&docid=PkB0TDgkdOkHwM&ei=62ZlVqyJAYGz-wGjuK4I&tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwjsqp6tzMnJAhWB2T4KHSOcCwEQMwhGKCIwIg" alt="statistic">
          <p class="center-block num"> 100 </p>
          <div class="center-block statistic"> statistic #3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="stat col-md-3 hide">
          <img class="center-block" src="https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/0e/Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg/64px-Ski_trail_rating_symbol-green_circle.svg.png&imgrefurl=https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piste&h=64&w=64&tbnid=b1-OSFz6e0HHrM:&docid=PkB0TDgkdOkHwM&ei=62ZlVqyJAYGz-wGjuK4I&tbm=isch&ved=0ahUKEwjsqp6tzMnJAhWB2T4KHSOcCwEQMwhGKCIwIg" alt="statistic">
          <p class="center-block num"> 100 </p>
          <div class="center-block statistic"> statistic #4</div>
        </div>
</div>
<div id="learning-experience"> learning-experience</div>
<div id="success">success </div>


</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#mission, #why-cs, #learning-experience, #success {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

#mission {
  background-color: green;
}
#why-cs {
  background-color: orange;
}
#learning-experience {
  background-color: #000;
}
#success {
  background-color: #220000;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {

  autoScroll();
  animateStat();


});

function autoScroll() {
  $('.sub-nav a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var sectionID = $(this).attr('href');
      alert($(sectionID).offset().top);
      $('html body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(sectionID).offset().top
      }, 1000)
  })
}

function animateStat(){
  var stats = $('#why-cs').offset().top - 200,
      statistic = $('.stat');


  $(window).scroll(function () {
     var delay = 400;

    if ($(window).scrollTop() > stats) {
      $.each(statistic, function () {
          statistic.removeClass('hide');
          statistic.delay(delay).addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
          delay += delay;
      })
    }
    if ($(window).scrollTop() < stats) {
      statistic.removeClass('animated fadeInUp');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Web-Dev. Any further thoughts on the 2 answers below?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `setTimeout` function in `each` loop like following. Hope this will help you.

```
$.each(statistic, function (i, item) {
     setTimeout(function(){
        $(item).removeClass('hide');
        $(item).addClass('animated fadeInLeft');
     }, 400*i)           
})
```

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8t881403/5/) link: https://jsfiddle.net/8t881403/5/

**Update:** `statistic = $('.stat')` selects all element with class `stat`. So when you add or remove class to `statistic` all element are get animated at a time. 
And the `delay` method only works for numeric CSS modifications. For these reasons your code is not working.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Can you explain to me what was wrong with my code and why your's worked?

Comment: That's a horrible way of doing it?! setTimeout will get you into all types of trouble if there's any other JS involved.

Comment: In this case no other `js` is involved @AlexanderWigmore

Comment: How do you know @Azim?

Answer (score 0):

I've had to change the JS logic quite a lot.
You cannot get the `offset` value of an element that is hidden(`.hide`) as the browser doesn't have it in the element tree at all, and basically doesn't store any info about it.

Further from that, you were on the right track using `each` however, you need to take advantage of the `this` keyword within it so that you apply the rules to that iteration of the loop, instead of all matching classes.

For that reason I just made it `display:block` and `opacity: 0` instead.
Here's a JS Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/wigster/fe3e36j9/

The new JS:

```
var $win = $(window);
var $stat = $('.stat'); // Change this to affect your desired element.

$win.on('scroll', function () {
    var scrollTop = $win.scrollTop();

    $stat.each(function () {
        var $self = $(this);
        var prev=$self.offset();
        console.log(scrollTop);
        console.log(prev.top);
        if ( (scrollTop - prev.top) > -300) {
          $self.css('opacity', '1').addClass('animated fadeInLeft ');
        } else {
          console.log('n');
        }

    });

}).scroll();
```

For future reference I also have this created as a simple go to for animating on scroll:
http://trulycode.com/bytes/simple-appear-on-scroll/